# responsive website not working according to width

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

It is showing red background on "285px" width whereas i have set "1140px" as max width when i switch to responsive website. and if i use min-width it does the opposite ,effect does not shows till 256/276px and then it comes.i have tried both max and min width , i have to do it with external linking but on internet there is everyone showing inline.please help,i am stucked with this problem for over 3 days.

It is showing red background on "285px" width whereas i have set "1140px" as max width when i switch to responsive website. and if i use min-width it does the opposite ,effect does not shows till 256/276px and then it comes.i have tried both max and min width , i have to do it with external linking but on internet there is everyone showing inline.please help,i am stucked with this problem for over 3 days.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/* navbar */

#top{
    display:flex;
    position: relative;

}

#top ul{
    display:flex;
    margin: auto;

}
#top ul li{
   
    margin:10px;
    font-size: 80px;
    list-style: none;

}
#top ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:beige;
   padding:20px 70px 20px 70px;

}
#top ul a:hover{
    border:4px solid brown;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    border-radius: 30px;

}

.logo img{
    margin-top:55px;
    margin-left:30px;
    height:177px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 
}
#top::before{
    content:"";
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.4;
 
}
/* middle */
#middle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
  
}
#middle::before{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background:url('/photo/buffet-315691.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    height:94%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.7;
  
}
.head {
    color:black;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
  
}
.para {
 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 55px;
    color:#332d2d;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  
}
.para p{
    width:2000px;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color:#332d2d;

}
.head h1{
    margin-top:400px;
}
/* speciality */
.op{
    border: 16px solid black;
    display:block;
    width: 1500px;
    height:1100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    background:rgb(238, 222, 222);
}
.he{
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    
}
.op img{
    display:block;
    width: 706px;
    height: 442px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;

}
#speciality{
 
    display: flex;
    margin:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    
}
#Box{
    
    height:800px;

    margin: auto;
  
    position: relative;
}
.group{
    display: block;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
    height:400px;

}
.group input{
    padding:30px;
    margin:30px;
    height:40px;
    width:800px;
}
.riv{
    height:150px;
    width:800px;
    padding:30px;
    margin:30px;
}
#form{
    position: relative;
}
#form::before{
    content:"";
    background: url('/photo/food-2569257.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.4;
  
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#form h1{
    font-size: 200px;
}
.group input{
    font-size: 50px;
}
#mi{
    position: relative;
}
.riv{
    font-size: 50px;
}
#form h1{
   
    margin-left: 300px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:1200px)" href="ph.css"> 


<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/photo/l.jpeg" alt="ISSUE">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Recipie</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section id="middle">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>It's Easy to cook</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="para">
            <p>Recipies made simple , so that you can cook without compromising on taste,also order the food you like
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi similique debitis dolorum laudantium,
                iusto minima, neque perspiciatis amet, officiis reprehenderit expedita temporibus. Soluta dolorum velit
                vel eum corrupti veritatis! Reprehenderit delectus voluptatem repellat doloremque?</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="mi">
    <div class="head he">
        <h1>Our speciality</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="speciality">
        <div class="op">
            <img src="/photo/dalmakni.jpg">
            <h1 class="head">Dal Makhni</h1>
            <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus quas harum ab animi,
                asperiores perspiciatis earum quos, possimus praesentium pariatur amet. Ab temporibus labore minus
                commodi, dolorem placeat maxime illum?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="op">
            <img src="/photo/aloo.jpg">
            <h1 class="head">Aloo Cheese Paratha</h1>
            <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus quas harum ab animi,
                asperiores perspiciatis earum quos, possimus praesentium pariatur amet. Ab temporibus labore minus
                commodi, dolorem placeat maxime illum?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="op">
            <img src="/photo/biryani-1141444_1920.jpg">
            <h1 class="head">Veg Biryani</h1>
            <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus quas harum ab animi,
                asperiores perspiciatis earum quos, possimus praesentium pariatur amet. Ab temporibus labore minus
                commodi, dolorem placeat maxime illum?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="op">
            <img src="/photo/paneer.jpg">
            <h1 class="head">Matar Paneer</h1>
            <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus quas harum ab animi,
                asperiores perspiciatis earum quos, possimus praesentium pariatur amet. Ab temporibus labore minus
                commodi, dolorem placeat maxime illum?</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="form">
        <h1 class="head">Details</h1>
        <section id="Box"><form actions="">
            <div class="group">
                <label class="name" id="nam">
                <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="enter your name">
                <input type="number" name="name" placeholder="Enter your number">
                <input type="email" name="name" placeholder="Enter your email">
                <textarea name="name" class="riv" placeholder="enter review"></textarea>
                </label>
                </form>
            </div>
    </section>
</head>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please add code snippet and technical details about the ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can do external linking. No problem. The below css code is what I have used on my page. It does exactly what you need. You will have to use media queries for this.

CSS Code below for your reference. You will want to focus on the media queries (@media) code for the container class.

Read the comments in the code. It will answer your questions.
**This is my main.css file**

```
/*________________________________________________________________________________
Wrapper
__________________________________________________________________________________*/
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid var(--ColGrey80);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}
/*________________________________________________________________________________
Container
__________________________________________________________________________________*/
/* This applies from 0px to 600px - Primarily Mobile*/
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--ColPastelGreen);
}
/* This applies from 600px onwards - Primarily Laptop*/
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
    .container{
        max-width: 450px;
        height: 80vh;
        border: 1px solid var(--ColAppHighlight);
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: var(--ColWhite);
    }
}
```

**HTML Code Below:**
This is for you to check on how you link your css file to the html file. Check the  tag where you find index.css & main.css. These are the external css files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Crogress</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="lib/images/c.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Crogress</h1>
                <p id="signin">Sign in</p>
            </div>
            <form id="form">
                <div id="inputFields">
                    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="textbox" autocomplete="off" value="User Name">
                    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="textbox" autocomplete="off" value="Password">
                    <div id="error"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <a id="create" href="http://">Create Account</a>
                    <button type="button" onclick="authenticate();">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir, i have to add externally this media

Comment: Yes. You can add externally. Let me show you my html code.. I have added my HTML code in the answer I sent you already.

If you need further support, let me know.